# Capture error GRPC 14 UNAVAILABLE service unavaible NestJS

Tags: node.js, grpc, nestjs

I am developing `una app web con Nest` and microservice by `grpc`.
At the first moment, I don´t have a `server grpc`, only a client, and get `error 14 UNAVAILABLE`. Ok, I want to control this error.
I don´t want to send the `error 500 Internal Server`.
How could I do it, with my own exception?

I have tried to create exceptions at the controller level, which inherit from `GrpcExceptionFilter` and do not work, since it does not capture the error.
I have also created a filter that captures the `HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE` exception and does not work either

I need to be able to control the error that occurs when the microservice is not available